# Issue with AWS Beanstalk command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been using EBS without any problems. Today, I've added load balancer, and uploaded my package with the following configuration:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

However, when I am trying to launch the package, I get the following error:

> Application deployment failed at 2016-11-23T14:07:40Z with exit status
>   7 and error: container_command 01_reload_nginx in
>   .ebextensions/environment.config failed.

Whats going on?

These are the logs:

> [eb-cfn-init]:   Successfully execute hooks in directory
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre. [eb-cfn-init]:
>   [2016-11-23T16:09:31.193Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
>   [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.506Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application
>   deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild]
>   : Starting activity... [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.507Z] INFO 
>   [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application] : Starting activity... [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.842Z] INFO 
>   [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application/Command
>   01_reload_nginx] : Starting activity... [eb-cfn-init]:
>   [2016-11-23T16:09:31.868Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application/Command
>   01_reload_nginx] : Activity execution failed, because: 
>   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError) [eb-cfn-init]: 
>   [eb-cfn-init]:  [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.868Z] INFO  [2680]
>   - [Application deployment ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application/Command
>   01_reload_nginx] : Activity failed. [eb-cfn-init]:
>   [2016-11-23T16:09:31.868Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application] : Activity failed. [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.868Z] INFO 
>   [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild]
>   : Activity failed. [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.884Z] INFO 
>   [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity failed.
>   [eb-cfn-init]: [2016-11-23T16:09:31.884Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application
>   deployment ttttttt@4/StartupStage0] : Activity failed. [eb-cfn-init]:
>   [2016-11-23T16:09:31.884Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application deployment
>   ttttttt@4] : Completed activity. Result: [eb-cfn-init]:   Application
>   deployment - Command CMD-SelfStartup failed

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue, happening during platform upgrades. I contacted AWS support about this: they said they couldn't reproduce but had a very interesting piece of information which actually prevents this situation.

> However, [command: "sudo service nginx reload"] is not necessary as nginx service restarts automatically after every successful deployment.

So you can just remove the

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

part of the script so you'll never have the reload failure.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I added the 01_reload_nginx command because I needed to update the client_max_body_size and the command will reload nginx with the new configuration. I only faced a problem when I upgraded my platform to "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.12.14". Removing the 01_reload_nginx section solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly your NGINX configuration file is broken and doesn't pass the test when NGINX reloads. During service reload, NGINX first checks your configuration file, if configuration is correct a HUP signal is sent to the NGINX process which gracefully shuts down old workers and starts new ones with the new configuration.

In order to verify your configuration file you can use below command:

`/usr/bin/nginx -t -c ~/mynginx.conf`

`-t` = Don’t run, just test the configuration file. NGINX checks configuration for correct syntax and then try to open files referred in configuration.

`-c filename` = your configuration file location (if not default)

You should be able to test your config with below command also (depending on what operating system you are on):

`service nginx configtest`

The first variation is preferable as it will also print any info, warning as well as error messages in your NGINX configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how is that possible? literally, nothing has changed in either the environment settings or in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting because our elastic beanstalk deployment also failed yesterday on .ebextensions. It worked an hour later...

AWS deployed a new version of EB and S3 around the same time...
https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/6845489088399156
https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/8532186109690530

I wonder if AWS is at fault?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar problem. There were couple of them

1) There was a duplicate entry in my config which was causing problem. Running the command directly on the command line showed me the problem

```
service nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] "keepalive_timeout" directive is duplicate in 
/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.custom.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

So removing that entry helped.

2) Instead of reload you can try restart which worked for me.

```
command: "service nginx restart"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with nginx, java code.

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

In abouve code I added

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

sudo and this error is solved successful deployment was done.