# AWS Elasticbeanstalk deployment suddenly failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, deployment, playframework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a play application written in Scala that I deploy using elastic beanstalk. Up until now this has worked fine, but a few days ago new deployments started failing. The error message in `eb-activity.log` that I get is:

```
[2020-11-25T20:54:29.150Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2020-11-25T20:54:29.150Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2020-11-25T20:54:29.150Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-11-25T20:54:58.963Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Activity execution failed, because:  (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by:  (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2020-11-25T20:54:58.964Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Activity failed.
[2020-11-25T20:54:58.964Z] INFO  [3127]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201125b@152/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Activity failed.
```

Deploying to other test environments works, here is the relevant log line when it works:

```
[2020-11-25T23:19:51.549Z] INFO  [3058]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201126a@482/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2020-11-25T23:19:51.549Z] INFO  [3058]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201126a@482/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-11-25T23:19:53.910Z] INFO  [3058]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201126a@482/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Starting awslogs: [  OK  ]
  Enabled log streaming.
[2020-11-25T23:19:53.910Z] INFO  [3058]  - [Application deployment givinga-1.8.1-20201126a@482/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logstreaming/hooks/config.
```

So my question is, what is the log streaming doing here? What could cause it to fail? There doesn't seem to be a way for me to delete this addon, or even to configure it.

Comment: [Why I get ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787243/why-i-get-elasticbeanstalkexternalinvocationerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which AWS region are you using for your EB environments?
If that deployment worked yesterday and you didn't make changes. It is probably that `us-east-1` had a failure today.
https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still persists today despite the outage apparently being fixed. The problem appeared on Monday anyway, so I think it is independent.

Comment: Also, although all my environments are in US-East-1 which is the zone that was affected, only one environment fails to deploy, all the others work fine.

Comment: Actually, in the end I think this was the issue, it simply persisted longer than expected, and there was another bug that caused deployment to fail after this one, but thankfully the other bug was easy